# Powershell Combine Switch Statement

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I have the following Powershell code:

```
$dow = (get-date).DayOfWeek
switch($dow) {{"Sunday"}{$report_Day = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Day}{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"}{$report_Day = (Get-Date).Day}}
switch($dow) {{"Sunday"}{$report_Month = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Month}{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"}{$report_Month = (Get-Date).Month}}
```

Wonder if it is possible to combine the 2 switch statements into 1 - something such as:

```
$dow = (get-date).DayOfWeek
switch($dow) {{"Sunday"}{$report_Day = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Day, $report_Month = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Month}{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"}{$report_Day = (Get-Date).Day, $report_Month = (Get-Date).Month }}
```

I tested it it wouldn't work but I wonder if there is a mean to combine them.

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to get the date of the Friday before **if a date falls on a weekend**? You can **calculate** it directly instead of checking multiple conditions…

Answer (score 1):

First: Do yourself, and anyone who will read your code in the future, a favor and format your code so that it's readable. Whitespace doesn't cost you anything and it will save you difficulty later on.

Second: What does your code do on Friday & Saturday?

The issue is the commas between the statements in your `switch` statement. They should be separate lines (again, formatting will help you) or if you *must* put them on the same line, terminate each statement with a semicolon (<kbd>;</kbd>).

```
$dow = (get-date).DayOfWeek
switch ($dow) {
    "Sunday" {
        $report_Day = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Day;
        $report_Month = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2).Month;
        break
    }
    {($_ -eq "Monday") -or ($_ -eq "Tuesday") -or ($_ -eq "Wednesday") -or ($_ -eq "Thursday")} {
        $report_Day = (Get-Date).Day;
        $report_Month = (Get-Date).Month
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Good points, but both blocks will execute in any case - `{"Sunday"}` and `{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"}` will both return `$true`